# On Windows 7, is there a way to map a printer such that it is available for all sessions?

Tags: windows-7, networking, desktop, administrator, network-printer

While logged in as the normal console session user (i.e. no elevated privileges) I can start a custom Windows application the normal way, and I can send a file to a printer by pressing a print button on that application.  The file by default, goes to the default printer, and prints just fine.  However, if I start the same application from within session 0, to start in session 1, say by launching it from a Windows service, the default printer is no longer defined for that application.  In fact, even if I try to set the default printer programmatically within the application by using the Windows API “SetDefaultPrinter("\server\printerName")”. The location (  eg. "\server\printerName" ) is not recognized. (as it was when run from within session 1)

My question: Using network or desktop administration methods on Windows 7, is there a way to define a default printer such that it is available from any session?

Comment: Clarification, you want to be available from any session user or service, or do you just care that the printer just works from a service session and that is your main goal?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Actually your question is timely.  I just had a conversation with another person who suggested that simply by having a printer (or printers) available to a service running in session 0, I could print files right from the service.  That would be a way to solve our problem.  So, is that possible?  i.e. having printer(s) available to a service?  How do I set that up?